# ios facebook sdk posting photo results in Only Me

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use the facebook sdk on ios to post a photo to my timeline from my app, it's not showing up there.  Instead it goes into a custom photo album (which I like) but I'm having to first manually approve the photo, then the photo shows on my timeline as "Only Me" and I have to change those permissions before anyone else can see the post.

[image]

Obviously this isn't ideal for a photo editing app.

I'm using variations of code that I've found here and in their samples.  I can post the code if it will help but it's working code from here.  It's almost like it's stuck with an "only me" setting even though in my code I'm requesting:

```
defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
```

I have not submitted my fb app detail page yet but I moved my fb app out of sandbox and in to live.  It's working that it's uploading the photo to my profile...

what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I discovered that the app itself is set to "only me".  In app center: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my when I find the app and hit settings.. it's set to only me.  I need that to be set to at least Friends or Friends of friends by default.  Of the sample fb apps that I've compiled.. some of them also show only me - like Scrumptious and SessionLoginSample, which is probably where I got my login code.  HellowFBSample is set to Friends.

Any ideas on why this is being set to useless permissions by default.  I can't expect users to switch the permissions.

UPDATE 2:

I'm going to go ahead and post that code.. cause I found my error.. maybe it will help someone.  Actually the code I got from here:

[FBSession: an attempt was made reauthorize permissions on an unopened session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695312/fbsession-an-attempt-was-made-reauthorize-permissions-on-an-unopened-session)

I've edited the checked answer there but I copied that code and it had:

```
        [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_action"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){
                                              [self publishStory];
                                          }];
```

publish_action is wrong.  It has to be publish_actions with an S.  Otherwise you get what I was getting.  It saves the photo privately but sets the app to "only me" since you don't really have permission to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this. but before you upload you must request permission from Facebook.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                             self.image, @"picture",
                                                             self.captionTextField.text, @"name", nil];
                              FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                                                              parameters:params
                                                                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                              [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                               {

                               }];
```