# Import user read and want to read book using facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on book related app. I'm fetching user likes books using me/books and it's not required any extra permissions and working fine.

Now I want user **finished** and **want to read books**

1. **me/books** - no extra permission is required
2. **me/books.reads** and **me/books.wants_to_read** are required **user_actions.books** permission.

When I try to login with permission "user_actions.books". I'm getting following error.

Error :
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x10d055b80 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)", com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}

Code :

```
-(void)importBooksFromFacebook{

// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_actions.books"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {


         // If the session was opened successfully
         if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
             NSLog(@"Session opened");
             // Show the user the logged-in UI
             // successful login now import book using access token
             return;
         }
         if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
             // If the session is closed
             NSLog(@"Session closed");
             // Show the user the logged-out UI
             [self userLoggedOut];
         }

         // Handle errors
         if (error){
             NSLog(@"Error");
             NSString *alertText;
             NSString *alertTitle;
             // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
             if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
                 alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                 alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
                 [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
             } else {

                 // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
                 if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                     NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

                     // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
                 } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                     alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                     alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
                     [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];

                     // Here we will handle all other errors with a generic error message.
                     // We recommend you check our Handling Errors guide for more information
                     // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                 } else {
                     //Get more error information from the error
                     NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

                     // Show the user an error message
                     alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                     alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
                     [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
                 }
             }
             // Clear this token
             [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
             // Show the user the logged-out UI
             //[self userLoggedOut];
         }
     }];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by below stackoverflow answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696106/1237937

```
if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {
  /* 
   * if the current session has no publish permission we need to reauthorize 
   */
  if ([[[FBSession activeSession] permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {

        [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){
                                                  [self postPhoto];
                                              }];

    }else{
        [self publishStory];
    }
}else{
    /* 
     * open a new session with publish permission 
     */
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                         if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                             [self publishStory];
                                         }else{
                                             NSLog(@"error");
                                         }
                                     }];
}
```